# moving drupal 7 regions

Tags: drupal-7

Till this point, I know I can move Block into different Region but is there a way to move reorganized region itself or create custom regions? For example, I want to create another custom region on top of the sidebar and move content into it.

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you can do through a web interface, but rather requires you to write/modify the theme.  For an overview and illustrations, see the beginning of the theming guide on the Drupal website: http://drupal.org/node/171194